# Android AsyncTask and Thread life cycle

Tags: android, multithreading

I am a little confused about AsyncTask and Thread life cycle.
What happens to a processes threads when the OS enters the OnStart/OnStop and onResume/onPause sequences.
Are the threads affected by this sequence.
I ask this question because I am using sockets in the threads and killing the threads will kill the tcpip connections as well (I assume).
If the thredas are not killed then how do I 'reconnect' to them especially as they may will be 'connected' to an activity via a Handler.

Answer (score 2):

Threads are not automatically killed when the app goes to onStop or onPause, however, there is no guarantee it **won't** be killed.  Android will keep it running until it needs the resources that the thread is using.

Generally, if you want a persistent connection when an `Activity` closes, then put that in a `Service`.  You can run threads in it just like an Activity (to prevent blocking that usually occurs with connections), and it's far less likely Android will kill it.

Answer (score 0):

Internally, AsyncTask uses fixed thread pool. (See http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html )

So, even if AsyncTask finished, thread does not die. But thread in thread pool can be killed.