# Life Time of Thread in android

Tags: java, android, multithreading, thread-safety, android-lifecycle

I have a thread which start when the button is pressed, Thread contains the broadcast listeners and operations related to wifi Direct and finally it connect the android device with the searched peer,I want to know for how much time my thread will be alive?? My thread class is:

```
public class ConnectPeers extends Thread {



        private List<WifiP2pDevice> deviceList = new ArrayList<WifiP2pDevice>();
        Context mContext;
        private static final String TAG = "MainWiFiDirectActivity";
        WifiP2pManager wifiP2pManager;
        Channel wifiDirectChannel;
        IntentFilter peerfilter;
        IntentFilter connectionfilter;
        IntentFilter p2pEnabled;
        public ConnectPeers(Context mContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            this.mContext = mContext;

    }
       /**
           * Listing 16-19: Creating a WiFi P2P Manager Action Listener
           */
          private ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
            public void onFailure(int reason) {

          // Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),"wifi direct reason"+String.valueOf(reason),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              String errorMessage = "WiFi Direct Failed: ";
              switch (reason) {
                case WifiP2pManager.BUSY : 
                  errorMessage += "Framework busy.";
              //    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),errorMessage+String.valueOf(reason),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  break;
                case WifiP2pManager.ERROR : 
                  errorMessage += "Internal error."; 
            //      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),errorMessage+String.valueOf(reason),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  break;
                case WifiP2pManager.P2P_UNSUPPORTED : 
                  errorMessage += "Unsupported.";
             //     Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),errorMessage+String.valueOf(reason),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  break;
                default: 
                  errorMessage += "Unknown error.";
                  break;
              }
              Log.d(TAG, errorMessage);
            }
            public void onSuccess() {
                  // Success! 
                  // Return values will be returned using a Broadcast Intent
                }
              };

          /**
           * Listing 16-18: Initializing Wi-Fi Direct
           */
         private void initializeWiFiDirect() {
                wifiP2pManager = 
                  (WifiP2pManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_P2P_SERVICE);

                wifiDirectChannel = wifiP2pManager.initialize(mContext,mContext.getMainLooper(), 
                  new ChannelListener() {
                    public void onChannelDisconnected() {
                     initializeWiFiDirect();
                    }
                  }
                );
              }
         /**
           * Listing 16-21: Receiving a Wi-Fi Direct status change
           */
          BroadcastReceiver p2pStatusReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              int WiFiDirectState = intent.getIntExtra(
                WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE,
                WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_DISABLED);

              switch (WiFiDirectState) {
                case (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED): 
                Toast.makeText(mContext,String.valueOf(WiFiDirectState), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               discoverPeers();
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     @Override
                     public void run() {
                         if(!deviceList.isEmpty())
                         {
                                connectTo(deviceList.get(0));

                         }
                     }
                 }, 4000);

                  break;
                default: 

              }
            }
          };
          /**
           * Listing 16-22: Discovering Wi-Fi Direct peers
           */
          private void discoverPeers() {
            wifiP2pManager.discoverPeers(wifiDirectChannel, actionListener);
          }

          BroadcastReceiver peerDiscoveryReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
              wifiP2pManager.requestPeers(wifiDirectChannel, 
                new PeerListListener() {
                  public void onPeersAvailable(WifiP2pDeviceList peers) {
                    deviceList.clear();

                   deviceList.addAll(peers.getDeviceList());

                  }
                });
              Toast.makeText(mContext,"discovery called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

          };
          /**
           * Listing 16-23: Requesting a connection to a Wi-Fi Direct peer
           */
           void connectTo(WifiP2pDevice device) {
            WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
            config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
            config.groupOwnerIntent=15;
          // if( device.status==0)
            wifiP2pManager.connect(wifiDirectChannel, config, actionListener);
            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Connect to", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

//        wifiP2pManager.createGroup(wifiDirectChannel, actionListener);
          }
          /**
           * Listing 16-24: Connecting to a Wi-Fi Direct peer
           */
          BroadcastReceiver connectionChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

              // Extract the NetworkInfo
              String extraKey = WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO;
              NetworkInfo networkInfo = 
                (NetworkInfo)intent.getParcelableExtra(extraKey);

              // Check if we're connected
              if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {
                wifiP2pManager.requestConnectionInfo(wifiDirectChannel, 
                  new ConnectionInfoListener() {
                    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) { 
                      // If the connection is established
                      if (info.groupFormed) {
                        // If we're the server
                        if (info.isGroupOwner) {
                           // TODO Initiate server socket.
                         // initiateServerSocket();

                             Toast.makeText(mContext,"server"+info.groupOwnerAddress.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                        // If we're the client
                        else if (info.groupFormed) {
                          // TODO Initiate client socket.
                       //   initiateClientSocket(info.groupOwnerAddress.toString());

                             Toast.makeText(mContext,"client"+info.groupOwnerAddress.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        }
                      }
                    }
                  });
              } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Wi-Fi Direct Disconnected");
              }
            }
          };
         @Override
            public void run() {

             initializeWiFiDirect();    
                peerfilter = new IntentFilter(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION);
                connectionfilter = new IntentFilter(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION);
                p2pEnabled = new IntentFilter(WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);

                // When you are done
            mContext. registerReceiver(peerDiscoveryReceiver, peerfilter);
            mContext. registerReceiver(connectionChangedReceiver, connectionfilter);
            mContext. registerReceiver(p2pStatusReceiver, p2pEnabled); 
         }

}
```

Comment: You may find something here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363666/android-asynctask-and-thread-life-cycle

Comment: Why don't you put a timer (one in the start) and measure this time several times in various locations, then divide the sum to the total of the tries and see .. I don't think that anyone can give you even an approximate value, but a formula in the best scenario.

Comment: To make life easier, android gives `AyncTask` which you can use here. See the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know when your thread ends, you can pass it a Handler and and send a message to your mainActivity when your thread ends (ie: at the end of the run method)

If you want to know how long it will take before starting it, I don't think you can accurately do it.